# Rotate image and crop only inside the image: UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, crop, image-rotation

I have a question. I need to crop a rotated image but the crop rectangle must feet in the image. I'm using Microsoft toolkit for cropping the image but it does not support cropping rotated image, so I added rotation to image and now my problem is to fit the cropping rectangle into the rotated image and not let it get outside of the image. In the images below I'm showing cases. If there is something you need to know to answer this question write it I will add.

[Not rotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYGw.png)

[Rotated image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JT9T.png)

[What I'm expecting to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meRQ2.jpg)

**Update**:
Link to the project
https://github.com/Hakobyan888/ImageCropper

Comment: Can your rectangle move or just like the ImageCropper in the Microsoft toolkit, you can only move the image and can't continue when the image is beyond the bounds of the rectangle? In addition, can you provide a simple sample about what you have implemented currently for us to test?

Comment: No I can't move the rectangle. Everything is like in toolkit. Only the things I have changed is in the ImageCropper.Properties.cs I have added ImageRotation dependency property and ScaledImageValue. The scaling works fine but as mentioned in the question can't do rotation. I have added the project to github the link to that project will be in the question. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can calculate the scaling ratio of cropper according to the rotation angle of the image.

Comment: @Faywang - MSFT.
Can you give me a little bit more info

Comment: Based on the rotation angle of the image, you can get the relationship between the width and height of the cropper which has scaled and the angle. Then calculate the scaling ratio of cropper to scale it.