# How to add rotation to ImageCropper toolkit: UWP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to add rotation to ImageCropper Microsoft Toolkit but I cant figure out how.
Please let me know for some suggestions.
Here is my repository link.
https://github.com/Hakobyan888/ImageCropper

Comment: I wanted to create such a thing too, but coudn't figure out either.

Comment: I have replied to you in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740881/rotate-image-and-crop-only-inside-the-image-uwp), you can check it.